# Connecting a SQL query to a website using Node.js?

Tags: node.js

This is completely new territory to me so please go easy:) I currently have a website coded via Javascript and a SQL program that for the website's intaking data. From the research I have done so far, I could do so using an express data frame. I have been trying to play around with Node.js and currently, I have something that connects to a local host port, and i created a table and an insertion mechanism to that table using sql (I will include my code as of now below). But I couldn't figure out how i could connect the SQL query I have in mySQLWorkbench to a port. Could anyone please point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
// including both express and mysql
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

//creat a database connection
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '123456',
    database: 'nodemysql'
});

//connect
db.connect((err) => {
    console.log('MySql connected...');
});

//creaing a simple express server
const app = express();


// creating a database (rout)
app.get('/createdb', (req, res) => { //request and response object
    let sql = 'CREATE DATABASE nodemysql'; 
    // running the query
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) console.log('ERROR');
        console.log(result)
        res.send('Database created...');
    })
});

// create table
app.get('/createtable', (req,res) => {
    let sql = 'CREATE TABLE posts(id int AUTO_INCREMENT, title VARCHAR(255), body VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (id))';
    db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if(err) console.log('ERROR');
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Appointment table created..');
    })
});

// insert appt 1
app.get('/addappt1', (req, res) => {
    let appt = {title: 'appointment 1', body: 'Appointment 1 at 10 am'};
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO appts SET ?'; // ? is a place hold to what we put as the second parameter
    let query = db.query(sql, appt, (err, result) => {
        if(err) console.log('ERROR');
        console.log(result);
        res.send('Appointment 1 was added')
    });
});

// listening on port 3000
app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly?

Comment: I just wanted some pointers on how I could connect a SQL query to a port!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the port configuration:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : '123456',
    database: 'nodemysql',
    port: 1234
});
```

Check for connection options in the link: 
https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql